# gvisColumnChart multiple yvar

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis

I'm using shiny and googleVis to make à little app. I want to create a colomn chart with gvisColumnChart with 4 yvars. The legend show the 4 vars but there is only one variable (bar) in the chart. In this case, only the bars for "Courbature" appears in the chart.

Here's my code :

```
output$energie = renderGvis({
         gvisColumnChart(dataProfil, 
         xvar = "Date", 
         yvar = c("Courbature", "Sommeil", "Stress", "Energie"))
})
```

dataProfil is from a CSV file and look like this :

```
Date    Energie Courbature  Sommeil Stress  Entrainement    
2014-03-15  6      1            9     3     Pratique de rugby   
2014-03-18  3      6            3     4     Pratique de rugby   
2014-03-20  8      3            8     8     Pratique de rugby   
2014-03-21  6      7            5     5     Musculation niveau 2    
2014-03-25  6      2            6     6     Pratique de rugby   
2014-03-28  3      3            3     6     Pratique de rugby
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
dataProfil <- read.table(text = "Date    Energie Courbature  Sommeil Stress  Entrainement    
2014-03-15  6      1            9     3     'Pratique de rugby'   
2014-03-18  3      6            3     4     'Pratique de rugby'   
2014-03-20  8      3            8     8     'Pratique de rugby'   
2014-03-21  6      7            5     5     'Musculation niveau 2'    
2014-03-25  6      2            6     6     'Pratique de rugby'   
2014-03-28  3      3            3     6     'Pratique de rugby'"
                         , stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
require(googleVis)
runApp(list(
  ui = bootstrapPage(
    htmlOutput("energie")  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$energie = renderGvis({
      gvisColumnChart(dataProfil, 
                      xvar = "Date", 
                      yvar = c("Courbature", "Sommeil", "Stress", "Energie"))
    })  }
))
```

[image: googleVis example]